# Continue a task in iOS in the background, if the phone is locked

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin.forms

I am doing this app in Xamarin forms (PCL - ios and android) where I am fetching a large data from server (using httpclient), I am showing progress dialog to show the user that data is being fetched.

Lets say, user accidentally locks the iphone, these are the things that i see that is happening in my app.

1. Goes to background. But then after that app seems to get terminated.
2. Unlock the phone, app is presented with same screen that was shown before unlocking but no background process happened (probably because app terminated(but, why app terminated?))

My queries : 
1. Why doesn't the app continue the data fetching? Seem to work fine in android. 
2. What actually happens to the tasks once the iphone is locked?
3. How do i continue the task in background in iOS say I execute the http call in pcl?

Answer (score 4):

That is where iOS and Android differ. While Xamarin makes it easier to develop for both, in the end they still are just Android and iOS apps which have to comply with the rules of that operating system.

In iOS, as of version 9 you cannot run code in the background, as opposite to Android where you can. For iOS you will have to do some magic for that.
There is [this blogpost](http://arteksoftware.com/backgrounding-with-xamarin-forms/) which you can follow that describes somewhat what you want to do.

He states;

> Backgrounding is the term we use for the process of allowing some of
>   the code in our app to continue to execute while another app is in the
>   foreground. On iOS, prior to iOS 9, only a single app is allowed to
>   execute code at a time. This is referred to as the foreground app. If
>   you don’t change your code to tell iOS that you plan on running code
>   in the background, your app will be forcefully terminated and removed
>   from memory if your code attempts to execute in the background.
>   Android actually does allow code to run in a background activity, but
>   background activities are one of the first things to be terminated if
>   the operating system needs more memory. Instead, on Android, we should
>   use another special class called a Service.

So also have another look on how you do it in Android, because if you do it wrong, your transfer will be interrupted as well.

For implementing in iOS he uses this:

> In the `AppDelegate.cs` file in the iOS project, we will use Messaging
>   Center to subscribe to the Start and Stop messages. For convenience,
>   I've wrapped the iOS apis in another class named
>   `iOSLongRunningTaskExample`. The important methods here for iOS are
>   `UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask ("LongRunningTask", OnExpiration)` and
>   `UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask (taskId)`. These are
>   the methods that tell iOS that we'll be running code in the background
>   and to not terminate our app.

He then implements them like this:

```
[Register ("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate  
{
    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<StartLongRunningTaskMessage> (this, "StartLongRunningTaskMessage", async message => {
            longRunningTaskExample = new iOSLongRunningTaskExample ();
            await longRunningTaskExample.Start ();
        });

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<StopLongRunningTaskMessage> (this, "StopLongRunningTaskMessage", message => {
            longRunningTaskExample.Stop ();
        });
    }
}

public class iOSLongRunningTaskExample  
{
    nint _taskId;
    CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    public async Task Start ()
    {
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource ();

        _taskId = UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask ("LongRunningTask", OnExpiration);

        try {
            //INVOKE THE SHARED CODE
            var counter = new TaskCounter();
            await counter.RunCounter(_cts.Token);

        } catch (OperationCanceledException) {
        } finally {
            if (_cts.IsCancellationRequested) {
                var message = new CancelledMessage();
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (
                    () => MessagingCenter.Send(message, "CancelledMessage")
                );
            }
        }

        UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask (_taskId);
    }

    public void Stop ()
    {
        _cts.Cancel ();
    }

    void OnExpiration ()
    {
        _cts.Cancel ();
    }
}
```

For the details have a look at the post.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation Gerald! Can you tell me if there is a way to stop the tasks altogether when i lock the phone or the app goes to background state. Since I found out now that the fetching takes nearly 5 mins to complete, I don't want to do it in the background. Or is it fine?

Comment: The only thing you can do is detect that your app is going to the background and pause it or something. Check the default events in your `App.xaml.cs`. I don't think you can detect that the device is being locked specifically. But maybe you won't have to because probably the event for going to the background is called then as well.